Can I have several versions of the same package installed side-by-side?
I used to use libraw 0.19.0 in my project. Then I started using vcpkg and allowed it to just install the latest libraw package (0.21.2). Then I noticed that the images I was getting from libraw looked kind of different, and wanted to go back to 0.19.0 to see if the libraw version was the culprit. So I added this to my vcpkg.json:
  "overrides": [
        { "name": "libraw", "version": "0.19.0" }
    ]

... and now I'm waiting for Visual Studio to download/build that libraw version (takes about 40 minutes).
Finally, after this test, I will probably want to go back to the latest version. Is this going to take another 40 minutes, or does vcpkg still keep the built 0.21.2 in some sort of cache?
If it does not keep it, then what can I do to avoid this huge waiting (time waste) in the future?
